# Como precargar archivos antes de que aparezcan

Tags: javascript, html

Antes de nada gracias a quien pueda echarme un cable.

Estoy intentando cargar una serie de imágenes cuando se entra en la página, para que cuando en el transcurso de la navegación de la misma, estás aparezcan de forma instantánea y no tengan periodos (aunque sean rápidos) de espera.

El código Javascript que tengo es el siguiente, de un ejemplo que encontré por internet, pero no veo que me funcione.

```js
var imageData = [
    //Example Images
    'logo.png','verde.png','rojo.png',
    'play.jpg','mano-up.png','mano-down.png'
];

function preloadImage(data)
{
    var base_path = 'images/';
    var total = data.length;
    var i = 0;
    var imgArray = new Array();
    for(i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
    var tmpImage = new Image();
    tmpImage.src = base_path + data[i];
    imgArray.push(tmpImage);
    }
}

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.addEventListener("load", function(){
    preloadImage(imageData);
})
```

EN el html de mi página, estas imágenes van apareciendo o desapareciendo por medio de background-image añadiendo clases a algunas etiquetas por medio de js y otras imágenes están añadidas con las etiquetas img.

Al parecer no funciona porque cuando ejecuto por medio de js una función en la que un div cambia de display none; a display flex; se ve que tarda en cargar si la conexión es lenta.

No se que estoy haciendo mal la verdad.

Comment: Tuve una duda similar, puede que te ayude:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24114/saber-cuando-el-navegador-ha-procesado-una-imagen-despu%c3%a9s-de-cargarla

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @ArnauCastellví pero la mayoría de las imagenes las muestro como background-image a una clase, por lo que no podría suar el canva

Comment: De hecho si que podrías, pero no importa, porque el uso de la imagen en un canvas solo es un truco para asegurarse que la imagen realmente terminó de cargar, luego ese canvas no lo usas.